# Rails render loads partial only

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I want to reload a part of page after a link clicked. Let's say I want to implement a click counter. Here's what I've done.

In **show.html.erb**

```
<div id="downloads"><%= render(partial:'downloads', locals: {user: @user}) %></div>
```

in **_downloads.html.erb**

```
<% user.attachments.each do |attachment| %>
  <%= attachment['download_count'] %>
    <br>
  <%= link_to 'download', {controller: 'files', action: 'download', attachment: attachment, user: user}%>
<% end %>
```

in **show.js.erb**

```
$("#downloads").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('downloads', locals: {user: params[:user]})) %>")
```

in **files_controller.rb**

```
def download
  user = User.find(params[:user])
  # increasing attachment's dl count
  # ...
  render(:partial => 'users/downloads', locals: {user: user}, :layout => false)
end
```

*As a result* it replaces whole page with partial. What's wrong?

**EDIT ONE**

Added `remote: true` to link_to as Anchor said.

```
<%= link_to 'download', {controller: 'files', action: 'download', attachment: attachment, user: user}, remote: true %>
```

in **files_controller.rb**

replaced  `render(:partial => 'users/downloads', locals: {user: user}, :layout => false)` with

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js {  render(:partial => 'users/downloads', locals: {user: user}, :layout => false)}
end
```

Trying to click link now: nothing happens at my page. Though in console:

> Processing by FilesController#download as JS
>     Parameters: {"attachment"=>{"download_count"=>"175", "filename"=>"filename.doc", "id"=>"2fd9adbf6172740d46060000", "type"=>"appli"}, "user"=>"7fbceaa661727417f55e0000"}
>     Rendered users/_downloads.html.erb (60.7ms)
>   Completed 200 OK in 106ms (Views: 63.1ms)

I think that I am facing a javascript problem now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, finally solved my problem. 
I replaced in my controller

`render(:partial => 'users/downloads', locals: {user: user}, :layout => false) # rendering html:(`

with something like

`format.js {render(users/show.js.erb)} # should render js!`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your controller is returning an HTML response instead of a Script response. Try adding the parameter :remote => true in your link_to:

```
<%= link_to 'download', {controller: 'files', action: 'download', attachment: attachment, user: user}, :remote => true %>
```

and make sure that your controller has a corresponding format.js in the response block